# Selenium tests does not run when Internet explorer 9 or Virtual machine is minimised

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, internet-explorer-9, virtual-machine

Internet Explorer - version 9
Selenium - 2.42.2
language - JAVA
What steps will reproduce the problem?
1.Trigger a login test on windows VM on IE with the following capabalities:

```
  InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS=true
  InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING=true
  InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS=true
  InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_PERSISTENT_HOVERING=true
  InternetExplorerDriver.NATIVE_EVENTS=false
  InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL="https://***********.com
```

2.Minimise the VM and 
3.Wait for the selenium script to run and then maximise the VM to check if the tests are running fine.

What is the expected output? What do you see instead?
Expected Output: The login to the application should be completed.
Instead, the test is stuck in the login page. The user-id and password is not entered.(The webdriver is unable to identify the element)

Selenium version:2.42.2
OS:Windows 7
Browser:Internet Explorer
Browser version:9

The tests are triggered from jenkins server remotely. The tests run fine when it is in the foreground, but fails if the VM or IE is minimised.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the Protected Mode settings for each zone to same value (details are [here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#Required_Configuration)). Then don't set following capability -

```
 InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS=true
```

And also try without setting following capabilities (make sure zoom level set to 100%) -

```
  InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING=true
  InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS=true
```